# How to make default auto slug from title in DB?

Tags: python, django, slug

Im stacked with find out how to make default slug from title in DB

So i have:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

I have already added data in DB (*name*), and of course empty *slug*.

Problem: don't know how to set up **default slug**, generated from title from DB.

I guess Django should find all rows in DB with empty slug fields and do some slugify() and push slug to DB.

ALSO: my DB will be updated automatically almost everytime (not mannually from admin panel). That's why i need to make a slug after DJANGO understand that DB has new row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uses [django-autoslug](https://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug/fields.html). Don't trouble yourself with trying to redo something that has already been done.